# Visual C++ redistributable installed in Windows 8 Pro, but in control panel size is shown in kbs

Tags: windows-8, visual-c++-2010, redistributable

We have delivered a project which is developed in VC++ , MFC in VS2010 (Windows 7) to client. But client is using Windows 8 Pro x64 bit (Japanese Language/version), and he's unable to install the project. The error comes up saying problem in module - mfc100d.dll.

I had taken remote control for the client machine and tried installing Visual c++ redistributable 2010, it got installed but when I checked it in control panel the size of it was in kbs. I also installed Windows 8 pro x64 in my machine and tried doing it and was able to install it properly.

The size of Visual C++ redistributable was 11mb. How can this be solved?

Comment: Why did you deliver a debug build to a client anyway? Afaik the redist does not deliver the debug redistributables. Properly compile a release build without mixing the crt and mfc runtimes.

Comment: I didn't deliver debug build. It was build in release mode. Also i have used the same exe to install the project in my PC with windows 8 pro and it works. The problem is installation of C++ distributables not getting installed properly in client machine, size showed is in KB where as in my machine its 11mb

Comment: You have not actually delivered your project, you merely asked the client to debug your program.  You **must** deploy the release build of your program, you can't deploy the debug versions of the runtime libraries, like mfc100d.dll.  The release build will use mfc100.dll (no d), which is installed by the vcredist installer.  If you think you are deploying your release build but still have a dependency on mfc100d.dll then you are shipping *something* that wasn't built correctly.  Getting this right can be the other 90% of the project.

Comment: We have a developed program which use c# code inside the c++ MFC code. So while compiling we select Common Runtime... Option in project properties. Is it something related to that ?